# How to create chome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to create chrome extension ?
A paragraph is simply one or more consecutive lines of text, separated by one or more blank lines. (A blank line is any line that looks like a blank line — a line containing nothing but spaces or tabs is considered blank.) Normal paragraphs should not be indented with spaces or tabs.

Answer (score -1):

### steps:

1. create application folder
         ex: d:\apps_folder\app_01
2. create manifest.json file in the above  app_01 folder

   ```
     file content like this

   {   
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "name":"Give_Your_Extension",
       "description":"Give description about the Extension",
       "short_name":"Shot_Name_for_Extension",  
       "version": "0.1",
       "browser_action": {
                          "default_popup": "Home.html",
                          "default_icon" : "images/logo.png"
                         },   "permissions": [ ],
      "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';
                                  object-src  'self'"
   ```

   }
3. Create Home.html
   Place content what u want
    Ex:

```js
// main.min.js


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.tabs = [{}]
  $scope.winID = "";
  $scope.td = new Date();

  $scope.ping = function() {

    } // end ping method code
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  th {
    background-color: Green;
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="js/main.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    Window ID: {{winID}}

    <hr>

    <button ng-click="ping()">ping</button>
    <br>Length:{{tabs.length}}
    <br>

    <table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <th>DATE</th>
        <th>WINDOW_ID</th>
        <th>TAB_ID</th>
        <th>TAB_INDEX</th>
        <th>TAB_URL</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in tabs">
        <td>{{td|date:"yyyy/MM/dd '_' hh:mm:ss a"}}</td>
        <td>{{winID}}</td>
        <td>{{x.id}}</td>
        <td>{{x.index}}</td>
        <td>{{x.url}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

4. create images folder in app_01\images , and put logo png